# Is it possible to use a stored procedure in boolean statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that returns a decimal value, what's wrong with this code?
(as I executed this stored procedure, it returns 0.0 with these parameters)

```
declare @Existance decimal(18, 0)
set @Existance = exec SALSetExists4Exporttoinv;1 @SGL,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null

if ( @Existance !> 0.0 )
.
.
.
```

Comment: Your SP has an output parameter?

Comment: yes , and It's supposed to be 0

Comment: Your declaring as decimal so any int assigned to it will become decimal so 0 becomes 0.0. Try DECLARE @Existance BIT

Comment: Your problem is you have a semi colon after your stored procedure name. Should be `set @Existance = exec SALSetExists4Exporttoinv 1 @SGL,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null;`

Answer (score 0):

Three errors have been spotted;

1. A comma is missing between 2 of your parameters
2. the `!>` won't work
3. Numbering is not compulsory except if you've got several proc of same family

You can try the following;

```
declare @Existance decimal(18, 0)
set @Existance = exec SALSetExists4Exporttoinv  @SGL,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null

IF NOT (@Existance > 0.0 )
Begin
 ...
End
```

Comment: Semicolon is actually correct; procedures can be numbered in Sql Server. See [; number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) in `create proc` definition.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
EXEC @VariableName=StoredProcedureName @Param1, Param2
```